# How to convert ProxyObject in python multiprocessing manager to normal python object

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

I'm using the `multiprocessing` library in python 3.7.

In my use case, I start with a normal `list` of `dict`s - I use this to create a `ListProxy` object from a `SyncManager` which I then use in a pool to syncronise the `list` (created as below).

```
data = [{...},{...},{...}] # arbitrary list of dicts that I want to sync in a pool

with Manager() as manager:

  list_proxy = manager.list()
  for row in data:
    list_proxy.append(manager.dict(row))

  # ... list_proxy used in pool.starmap later
```

My question: is there a pythonic way to change my `ListProxy` back into a normal list once the pool has finished running? I looked through the docs and even into the source code and it seems the only way might be to use the `_getvalue()` method from the `BaseProxy` class - but this seems hacky, and I will also have to recursively 'un-proxy' any nested proxy objects.

I need to return the normal list to serialise it to json later in the code, `ProxyObject`s are not easily serialised.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just call the *"real"* object function on the proxy object and turn it into the *"real"* object. See this example of a proxy `dict` which I share across instances and later turn into a *"real"* `dict` in order to serialize it.

```
def main(state):
    # Do something to input
    dict_proxy['state'] = state

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    dict_proxy = manager.dict()

    num_cores = int(2)
    with Pool(num_cores) as p:
       p.map(main, ['AK', 'HI'])

    dict_real = dict(dict_proxy)
```